# Нажимая на collab юнити залагивает и больше не отвечает ни на что, в чем проблема?

Tags: unity3d

Не знаю в чем может быть проблема. Обновил до этой версии и начало. Переустанавливал 2 раза.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все просто, ты не нажимай)

Answer (score 0):

При больших размерах проектов у нас очень долго обновления заливались, при этом выглядит это как подвисание юньки, причем на очень длительный срок. Чем больше проектных изменений, тем дольше ожидание пока все оживет

Comment: переустановка винды помогла)

Comment: это хорошо что помогло, а то по закону подлости обычно долго и упорно ищешь решение и ничего не получается

Comment: согласен, надеюсь с таким я не так часто встречаться буду